# Oracle to Singlestore real time replication

Tags: singlestore

I have a specific requirement,

1. Ingest real time data from Oracle to Singlestore(we are searching a very fast search database). Volume will be quite high(100 million records in one table and we have several tables).
2. Singlestore will be kind of a replica for storing for example :- last 1 year of data with real time replication/updation/insertion .
3. Singlestore will be used for querying only to show data points in our dashboard and search.
4. Oracle will be used for insertion and updation only.

Can you let me know if Singletore is the right fit for this case and what are the possible options?
Does anyone have an prior experience for the same, please advice.

We are searching for a fast search database engine on top of our Oracle database. And I came across Singlestore, so wanted to know views of any user who has used this scenario already.

Answer (score 0):

this is feasible.

There is no way to get data directly from Oracle to SingleStore - there needs to be some lightweight middleware in between.

Option 1: Leverage SingleStore [pipelines](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/load-data/load-data-with-pipelines.html). You would push data from Oracle to a certified pipelines source like S3 or Kafka, and then the data will automatically be ingested into SingleStore via the pipeline once its pushed out of Oracle.

Option 2: Leverage a CDC platform. For example, SingleStore [replicate](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/load-data/load-data-from-a-data-source/singlestore-replicate.html) offered in partnership with [arcion.io](https://arcion.io) - you can use this to real time CDC from Oracle to SingleStore.